# Zip 3 Lists into a Tuple- Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, zip, tuples

Is there an optimized way to zip 3 lists, in order

```
zip(L1, L2, L3)
```

So that they result in a list of tuples, example:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
L2 = [a, b, c, d],
L3 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
```

Resultant List of Tuples Should look like:

```
[{1,a,1}, {2,b,2}, {3,c,3}, {4,d,4}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1> lists:zip3([1,2,3,4],[a,b,c,d],[1,2,3,4]).
[{1,a,1},{2,b,2},{3,c,3},{4,d,4}]
2>
```

Or you could implement it manually:

```
myzip3([], _, _) ->
  [];
myzip3([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) ->
  [{X,Y,Z}|myzip3(Xs,Ys,Zs)].
```

Or using accumulator:

```
myzip3acc(Xs, Ys, Zs) ->
  myzip3acc_do([], Xs, Ys, Zs).

myzip3acc_do(Acc, [], _, _) ->
  lists:reverse(Acc);
myzip3acc_do(Acc, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) ->
  myzip3acc_do([{X,Y,Z}|Acc], Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Comment: Note that due optimizations `myzip3acc/3` is not necessarily faster than `myzip3/3` in newer Erlang versions.

Answer (score 10):

It seems you need to use [lists:zip3/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zip3-3):

```
1> L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4].
[1,2,3,4]
2> L2 = [a, b, c, d].
[a,b,c,d]
3> L3 = [1, 2, 3, 4].
[1,2,3,4]
4> lists:zip3(L1, L2, L3).
[{1,a,1},{2,b,2},{3,c,3},{4,d,4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style):

```
zip3_cps([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs], F) ->
     zip3_cps(Xs, Ys, Zs, fun(L) -> F([{X,Y,Z}|L]) end);
zip3_cps([], _, _, F) ->
     F([]).
```

Test:

```
1> cps:zip3_cps([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], fun(X) -> X end).
[{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9}]
```